# Python requests proxies.txt IP:Port:User:pass

Tags: python, proxy

I am trying to use like a file where I store my proxies in it. I want to load these on a proxies on the requests module.

But the problem now is, my proxies are mixed up. Some proxies are with authentication, and some doesn´t.

So my proxies.txt looks like this

```
123.12.190.121:2323:user:pass
123.12.190.122:2323:user:pass
123.12.190.123:2323
123.12.190.124:2323:user:pass
123.12.190.125:2323
```

Some with authentication, some doesn´t.

now I want to call a command like this

```
response = session.get(URL, proxies=proxies)
```

with the loaded proxies stored in my proxies.txt

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From requests documentation you can use proxy with user/pass or without. Please check the following link:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

To use HTTP Basic Auth with your proxy, use the http://user:password@host/ syntax:

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}
```

So you need create proxies dictionary with the help or regular expression or splitting by ':' character. Then you can create proxy url like: `http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128 or http://10.10.1.10:3128.`

From documentation:
To give a proxy for a specific scheme and host, use the scheme://hostname form for the key. This will match for any request to the given scheme and exact hostname.Note that proxy URLs must include the scheme.

```
proxies = {'http://10.20.1.128': 'http://10.10.1.10:5323'}
```

Please check code snippet:

```
import re
import random

scheme = 'http://'
proxies = {}
with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        pr = line.strip()
        m = re.search(r'^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\:(\d+)\:([^\:]*)\:([^\$]*)$', pr)
        if m:
            print('user: ' + m.group(3))
            proxies[scheme + m.group(1)] = scheme + m.group(3) + ':' + m.group(4) + '@' + m.group(1) + ':' + m.group(2)
        else:
            proxies[scheme + pr] = scheme + pr

    print(proxies)

k = random.choice(list(proxies))
print(k + ' => ' + proxies[k])
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I load the proxies out of my .txt when I have mixed proxies with authentication, and some without?

Comment: Read .txt file line by line. Write regex to check if it has user/pass or not. if it has user/pass then add user:pass@ before ip:port otherwise set blank before ip:port. I'm sending you sample psudocode.

Comment: Yeah, would be pretty great, when you can send sample, I am pretty new to python, appreciate your help!

Comment: Please check code snippet now. Hope it'll help you. Also there are many ways to make to more efficient.

Comment: Thank you mate. Possible you edit it to a snippet in code format? Cause it is displayed in one straigt line now without wordwraps etc. Would be great!

Comment: Wow works perfectly!!! My last question: How can I choose a random proxy from the list?

Comment: Yeah, it really helps! When I try to use the random proxy like this `response = session.get(url, proxies=proxies[k], verify=False)` I get an error. How should i use the random proxy?

Comment: I think you should use: response = session.get(url, proxies={k: proxies[k]}, verify=False). not yet tested bu just guessed.